# Is this video wrong?? (multiple variable Chain rule)

Tags: real-analysis

Given the condition as below. (where $G: \Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R,~h,~k:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb 
R$)

The problem is ask to calculate $\frac{\partial H}{\partial y}(6,3,7)$. 
[image]

And below is the solution:
[image]

However, is the red block wrong? I think it should be $\begin{bmatrix}4\\0\\8\end{bmatrix}$. Am I correct?

Comment: Why do you think $\left. \frac{\partial h(u,v)}{\partial (\text{it's first slot)}} \right|_{(u,v) = (3,7)}$ is $4$ and not $-8$?  (I.e., show your work to get the alternative you are proposing.)

Comment: The video is correct. Note that those are $v$'s and not $y$'s, and $v$ is the first input of $h$ and $k$. Thus you should look at $\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}(3,7)$ and $\frac{\partial k}{\partial x}(3,7)$ to find those values.

Comment: I think that term you mentioned is $\left.\frac{\partial h(u,v)}{\partial (\text{it's SECOND slot)}}\right| _{(u,v) = (3,7)}$, since what it refers to is " $\partial v$ "

Comment: But $v$ is the argument in $k$'s _first_ slot. In other words: Yay for the positional notation of partial derivatives. $\partial_1G\cdot \partial_1 h + \partial_3 G \cdot \partial_1 k$ would not so easily lead to confusion.